# Does attempting a puzzle require a movement point or an action point?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In our last (and first) game, an investigator attempted to move through a room that had an obstacle which revealed a puzzle. He was unable to resolve the puzzle on his turn. We only counted the attempted move and puzzle solve as **one movement point**. Is this correct?

On his next turn, does he (or any other investigator for that matter) need to use a movement point to reattempt to solve the puzzle or an action point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very specifically a Movement Step that needs to be spent, not an action. From the rulebook (pg. 8):

> Unlike other cards in a room, Lock cards are revealed when an investigator attempts to move into the room. Before a player physically moves his investigator figure into the room, the keeper turns the Lock card faceup and reads it aloud to all players.

Additionally,

> If the player is unable to discard the proper card or solve the puzzle, then he cannot enter the room this turn (and wasted this Movement Step). When a moving investigator encounters an ability saying “this door is locked,” his figure remains in its current room and cannot move for this Movement Step.

At the end of the section, it makes this very specific (my emphasis):

> Lock cards are always resolved when an investigator attempts to ***enter*** the room...

In most situations, the Lock cards say "This door is locked" so you can't reattempt entering the room in the same turn. I guess you can move away from the door if you still have a Movement Step or Run Action remaining.

Answer (score 1):

I would say movement point or use the action as a move. So yes you are correct. I believe the manual says somthing about that if you encounter a locked door you stop your movement in front of the door.